# When using JOIN feature in Oracle, I have some question about when I am using extra ALIAS in this code

Tags: sql, oracle, join, subquery, sql-in

Before start, Sorry some of results and datas are written in Korean.

Here is a code that I currently am looking on.

```
SELECT S.*, D.DNAME
FROM STUDENT S, DEPARTMENT D
WHERE (SUBSTR(S.JUMIN,7,1),S.WEIGHT) IN (SELECT SUBSTR(JUMIN,7,1),MAX(WEIGHT)
FROM STUDENT GROUP BY SUBSTR(JUMIN,7,1))
AND S.DEPTNO1 = D.DEPTNO;
```

And here is the ***DEPARTMENT*** data.

[image: student data]

And this is the ***STUDENT*** data.
[image]

I got a result as I want. But I have some questions when I change this part of the code

```
WHERE (SUBSTR(S.JUMIN,7,1),S.WEIGHT) IN (SELECT SUBSTR(JUMIN,7,1),MAX(WEIGHT)
```

into this one

```
WHERE (SUBSTR(S.JUMIN,7,1),S.WEIGHT) IN (SELECT 
S.SUBSTR(JUMIN,7,1),MAX(S.WEIGHT)
```

What I do is simply put ***S*** infront of ***JUMIN*** and ***WEIGHT*** in line3.
But when I do this it shows me the whole data.
[image]

I thought JOIN ***ALIAS*** (which are *S*,*D* in this code) is used as way show that I have two tables to use that is labeled with S and D. *S* means this data is in ***STUDENT*** and *D* is in ***DEPARTMENT***.
But I think I get it in a wrong way.
Anyway I have no idea how this result is come out.

Comment: `s` is an alias. With the help of aliases you can specify from which source (table) the column comes. you assigned this to your table student in the from clause. in your where clause you use the student table again, but this is a different source. so what you want or need is a new alias

Comment: and just a hint. use the explicit join syntax and not the comma-based one

Answer (score 1):

This one is referring to your main table not the subquery table.

```
WHERE (SUBSTR(S.JUMIN,7,1),S.WEIGHT) IN (SELECT 
S.SUBSTR(JUMIN,7,1),MAX(S.WEIGHT)
```

Your original query is already correct. In which you already have a new result set based on your aggregation.

```
WHERE (SUBSTR(S.JUMIN,7,1),S.WEIGHT) IN (SELECT SUBSTR(JUMIN,7,1),MAX(WEIGHT)
```